# How to add Kotlin plugin for Gradle in Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, plugins, kotlin

How to integrate Kotlin plugin for Gragle in Android Studio (version 3.1 Canary 3)? I have searched the web and [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) documentation but no clear answer is present. I am not sure if the existing answers on this and other websites must be relied because there have been many changes done to Kotlin integration in Android Studio 3.1 Canary 3.

Answer (score 0):

setup kotlin from Android studio **Tools** - **Kotlin** -   **Configure kotlin in project**